# How to get a Token API with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I have to get a token from a URL for an API of "ile de France mobilité", I'm using Fetch and I don't understand how to do this. This is my actual code:

```
var client_id = "(my client_id)";
var client_secret = "(my client_secret)";
// var url_get = "https://traffic.api.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/v1/tr-global/estimated-timetable";
var grant_type = 'client_credentials'
var token_url = 'https://as.api.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/api/oauth/token'
var scope = 'read-data'

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',   
    },
    body: {
        grant_type: grant_type,
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        scope: scope
    }
}
const fetch_response = await fetch(token_url, options)
const json = await fetch_response
console.log(json)
response.json(json)
```

And for answer I have

'Other stuff and :'

```
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://as.api.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/api/oauth/token',
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Does someone know how to do this?

In my index.html I call this script:

```
async function asyncCall() {
    const api_url = `/trajet`
    const response = await fetch(api_url, {method: 'POST'})
    const json = await response
    //console.log(json)
}

asyncCall()
```

server:

```
const app = express()
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'))
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: and my route is:
`app.post('/trajet', async (request, response) =>`

Comment: `and my route is` irrelevant since your code never accesses that route - is the code you posted in a browser? It would be extremely odd (and insecure) if it is

Comment: so, anyway `const json = await fetch_response` should be `const json = await fetch_response.json()` for a start

Comment: don't post code in a comment - I think you misunderstand `fetch` response ... if `response = await fetch` then it isn't a Promise ... you need to use one of the methods like .text() or .json() etc to access response data

Comment: @JaromandaX so how can i show you my Code ?

Comment: edit the question?

Comment: When I do your things that say that 'unwaited json' or something like this

Comment: so `const json = await fetch_response.json()` causes an error? can you,  rather than guess, actually show what the error is

Comment: Okay :
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://as.api.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/api/oauth/token reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
But when i put .text() its working

Comment: this is with .text
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>401 Authorization Required</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Authorization Required</H1>
This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.<P>
<HR>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON` so the API isn't returning JSON

Comment: Well, there's your error - have you read the documentation for the API you're using, seems you haven't authenticated correctly

Comment: One last and **important** question ... are you trying to access that remote API in browser code or server code - I doubt that API works directly from the browser

Comment: When you ask a server you talk about node ? I put what a think is a server in my question

Comment: so, what you're saying is the code (the javascript in the question) is running in a browser

Comment: Yeah I run it with localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Status Code 401 Unauthorized indicates that your request lacks valid authentication credentials. So there must be a problem in your body that you are sending.

Try sending the body in this format:

```
body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + key + '&client_secret=' + secret,
```

Comment: THANKS its working thanks men, I have a question how can I put you as an answer ?

Comment: You are most welcome. Just click on the " ✓ " grey colored symbol to accept it as the answer.